# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression

Tags: vb.net, expression

This is the code that I am using:

```
Private Function ExpresionNullable(contenedor As ParameterExpression, prop As String) As MemberExpression

    Dim member As Expression
    member = Expression.PropertyOrField(contenedor, prop)
    Dim typeIfNullable As Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(member.Type)
    If typeIfNullable IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim callexpression As MethodCallExpression = Expression.Call(member, "GetValueOrDefault", Type.EmptyTypes)
        member = callexpression
    End If
    Return member
End Function
```

I have a model that has this property: `Public Property price As Decimal?` and when i try to use this: `exprPropiedad = Expression.Property(exprPropiedad, prop)` I get an error because is it's allow nulls, so i found that function but have problems to cast the **MethodCallExpression to MethodCallExpression**.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call the ExpresionNullable? Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code where i call that function:

```
Function GetExpresion(cont As ParameterExpression, props As String, subObject As IEnumerable(Of String)) As MemberExpression
        Dim exprProp As MemberExpression = Nothing
        If subObject IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each subObjeto In subObject
                If exprProp Is Nothing Then
                    exprProp = Expression.Property(cont, subObject)
                Else
                    exprProp = Expression.Property(exprProp, subObjeto)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If exprProp Is Nothing Then
            exprProp = ExpresionNullable(cont, props)
        Else
            exprProp = Expression.Property(exprProp, props)
        End If
        Return exprProp
    End Function
```

in general what i need is something simple, need to use this

> Expression.Property(exprPropiedad, subObjeto)

when the model has a property that allow null values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the return type of the `ExpresionNullable` method be `MemberExpression`, make it `Expression`.

The signature of the method should look like this:

```
Private Function ExpresionNullable(
                                  contenedor As ParameterExpression,
                                  prop As String) As Expression
```

You are trying to create an expression that calls the `GetValueOrDefault` method on the nullable property object using `Expression.Call`. This creates a method call expression (`MethodCallExpression`) which is not a `MemberExpression` (it is not assignable to `MemberExpression` and this is why you are getting the cast exception). `MemberExpression` is only for expressions accessing fields or properties.

Such proposed change will also require you to do changes in the `GetExpresion` method. You have to change the type of the return value to `Expression`. Also you have to change the type of the `exprProp` variable to `Expression`.

Depending on the rest of your code, such changes might effect other parts of your code. And you might need to make similar changes there.

**UPDATE:**

In my answer I am assuming that you are calling `GetValueOrDefault` intentionally because you want to get the default value of the nullable property type if the value of the property is null.

In case you need the expression to access the nullable property and not its value (or the default if it is null), then simply delete the `ExpresionNullable` method because you don't need it and replace any call to it with `Expression.Property(...`.

Comment: I changed the return value `MemberExpression` to `Expression` and that seems to work, thank you for the idea